Support for HiGHS solver in MathOpt [Google OR-Tools], python API
When will the support for HiGHS solver be implemented in MathOpt (ortools) ? I am using MathOpt using python API. I am using ortools==9.9.3963.
So for the below sample code, I get the following error :
RuntimeError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: solver type SOLVER_TYPE_HIGHS is not registered, support for this solver has not been compiled

Below is the dummy code:
from ortools.math_opt.python import mathopt
model = mathopt.Model(name="MIP")
x = model.add_integer_variable(lb=-1.0, ub=1.5, name="x")
y = model.add_integer_variable(lb=0.0, ub=1.0, name="y")
model.add_linear_constraint(x + y <= 1.5)
model.maximize(x + 2 * y)
params = mathopt.SolveParameters(enable_output=True)
result = mathopt.solve(model, mathopt.SolverType.HIGHS, params=params)

With GSCIP above runs fine though.

It is out in 9.10.
Note that this is still experimental. We have issues with Highs (some cases of memory corruptions that we are working with the Highs team on).
